# Exclude the combination of 2 columns only from my query

Tags: mysql

Sounds simple but I couldn't find the solution for it.

I have a table with 3 columns. Account, Amount, Date.

I want to get all entries except the ones of one specific account with negative amount. But I still want to get the entries of this account if amount value is positive.

So with this query I'm also not getting the entries from account1 with a positive amount.

```
select * from table where (account!='account1' AND amount<='0') AND date='2020-05-01'
```

Comment: thr last end reduce the date 1 one day so when you didn't have any such data,. also != not equal to accoun1, as you can see your query doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `WHERE NOT` in your statement.

Example schema:

```
      Account    Amount    Date
=====================================
1     Ben        200       2020-10-10   
2     Frank      200       2020-10-10   
3     Ben        -300      2020-10-12   
4     Ben        10        2020-10-16   
5     Mary       2000      2020-10-16   
6     Frank      -200      2020-10-18
7     Ben        -10       2020-10-18  
8     Ben        0         2020-10-20
```

Now if you build your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE NOT (account='Ben' AND amount<0);
```

you should get what you want (all records except the 3rd and 7th).

Edit: if you really only want to exclude records with *negative* amounts, you need to do `<` rather than `<=` as you did in your example above. Depends on whether you want row 8 to be included in the result or not.